# Difference between creating an array in constructor and declaration in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, declaration

While I was trying to create an array in c++ class, there arose a problem while using the constructor. Here is the code:

```
int stacksize = 100;
int* buffer;
int stackpointer[3]= {-1, -1, -1};
public:
threestack(int stacksize_u)
{
    int buffer_u[stacksize_u*3];
    this->buffer = buffer_u;
    this->stacksize = stacksize_u;
}
threestack()
{
    int buffer_u[(this->stacksize)*3];
    this->buffer = buffer_u;
}
```

This actually did not work. When I create the array in the declaration, however, it worked:

```
int stacksize = 100;
int buffer[300];
int stackpointer[3]= {-1, -1, -1};
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong while I was using the constructor?

PSS: Here is the whole class and test program:

```
class threestack
{
    int stacksize = 100;
    int* buffer;
    int stackpointer[3]= {-1, -1, -1};
public:
    threestack(int stacksize_u)
    {
        int buffer_u[stacksize_u*3];
        this->buffer = buffer_u;
        this->stacksize = stacksize_u;
    }
    threestack()
    {
        int buffer_u[(this->stacksize)*3];
        this->buffer = buffer_u;
    }

    bool push(int stacknum, int value);
    bool pop(int stacknum);
    int peek(int stacknum);
    bool empty(int stacknum);
};

bool threestack::push(int stacknum, int value)
{
    if(stackpointer[stacknum-1]+1 >= stacksize)
    {
        cout<<"Plz do not try to push to a full stack"<<endl;
        //        printf("stackpointer = %d\n", stackpointer[stacknum-1]);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        stackpointer[stacknum-1]++;
        buffer[stackpointer[stacknum-1]+(stacknum-1)*stacksize] = value;
        return 1;
    }
}

int threestack::peek(int stacknum)
{
    if(stackpointer[stacknum-1] < 0)
    {
        printf("No element in stack now.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("stackpointer = %d\n", stackpointer[stacknum-1]);
        return buffer[stackpointer[stacknum-1]+(stacknum-1)*stacksize];
    }
}

bool threestack::pop(int stacknum)
{
    if(stackpointer[stacknum-1] < 0)
    {
        printf("Plz do not try to pop an empty stack.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        stackpointer[stacknum-1]--;
    }
    return 1;
}

bool threestack::empty(int stacknum)
{
    if(stackpointer[stacknum-1] < 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    threestack test;
    test.push(1,5);
    //    test.pop(1);
    //    test.pop(1);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<101; i++)
    {
        test.push(2, i);
        printf("%d\n", test.peek(2));
    }
    cout<<endl;
    printf("The top of stack 1 is %d\n", test.peek(1));
    //    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please always post the complete class, because this way that's really not a compiling / valid piece of code

Comment: You should never hold on to a pointer of an object that goes out of scope. After the constructor is finished, `buffer_u` is no longer a valid memory location to refer to.

Comment: @crashmstr , thx man, this is really really helpful comment and easy to understand~

Comment: @user3320681: Also, turn on the warnings.  Every major compiler would issue a warning telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @MooingDuck I was using xcode and I think I have turned every warning on... But it didn't say anything...

Comment: @KevinY: Fascinating, you're right! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d427977b2ff4b39

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**C++ arrays have a fixed size at compile time**.
This is why your test module works - the size (=300) is known at compile time.
That's mandatory because the size of an array is in fact part of it's type, implying that
the type of `int[1]` is very different from `int[2]`.

Yet it is not known when you kind of "dynamically" create the array in the constructor.
The way out is allocating dynamic memory using the `new` and `delete []` operators.

Even better, try to use [`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` or `auto_ptr`](http://duncan.mac-vicar.com/2012/08/01/c-does-have-automatic-memory-management/).

Comment: No. Consider `new` and `delete` deprecated. Do **not** recommend it to beginners. Use automatic memory management instead.

Comment: `new int[10]` creates an array whose size is *not* known at compile time. What you mean to say is that variables of complete array-type have complete array type (that's tautological), and that the array size is part of the array type.

Comment: Thx~ But while I created it in the constructor, buffer should points to an array which is created while the program is running right? Do you mean that buffer_u was created as a fixed size array while compiling instead of been created as an array of 300 size while running?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int* buffer;
```

is not a declaration of an array. It is a declaration of a pointer to int.

In constructor

```
threestack(int stacksize_u)
{
    int buffer_u[stacksize_u*3];
    this->buffer = buffer_u;
    this->stacksize = stacksize_u;
}
```

all these two statements

```
    int buffer_u[stacksize_u*3];
    this->buffer = buffer_u;
```

are invalid. Firest of all sizes of arrays shall be constant expressions. Secondly you assign adrress of the first element of a local array to pointer buffer. After exiting from the constructor this address will be invalid because the local array will be destroyed.

You should either allocate dynamically array using operator new and assigning its value to data member buffer or use container `std::vector` instead of the dynamically allocated array.